# Dalvik memory fragmentation handling

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how does Dalvik memory fragmentation handling?
For example, if I have a an app allocation some small memory. but free some of them, and then later on trying to allocate a big chunk. How can Dalvik handle such request, with all the 'holes' in the heap?

I need help in understanding this from logcat:

```
11-15 02:50:21.837 D/dalvikvm(  990): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 16K, 40% free 9830K/16384K, paused 90ms, total 90ms
11-15 02:50:21.837 E/dalvikvm-heap(  990): Out of memory on a 5032864-byte allocation.
```

It said my application has use 9830K out of 16384K. And I understand 16M is the maximum heap size, it can't grow any further.

But that should leave 6554K free (16384k - 9830K). 
Why dalvik says 'out of memory on a 5032864 byte allocation. That is 4914K which is smaller that I have left.

Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in watching this [lecture](http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/).   You might also be interested in this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Answer (score -1):

Take a Look at this, It might help you to understand how to handle dalvik memory fragmentation

[Link1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

Answer (score -2):

Like most implementations of Garbage Collector (GC), the GC of Dalvik/Java uses double references: reference variables in memory don't point directly toward their objects but toward a second reference which finally point toward the individual objects.  Therefore, the GC is free to move around the memory allocations and fuses together the holes when the application need a big memory allocation without impacting in any way the various reference variables allocated by Java.

Comment: No exact idea about the difference for the remaining 6554K but don't forget that the 16M is not reserved 100% for you; as both the application and the running activity each need some memory beside what you are allocating.  Think about the buffers and the structure for reading a file, the memory needed to save the state of your activity, to change the display.  Even the GC need some memory for itself.  All this stuff take their own bite at the available 16M of heap size.

Comment: Sadly, this is incorrect for Dalvik. Dalvik's garbage collector is non-compacting, and so does not consolidate free space. 

It is possible that a future version of Android (L or later) will have a compacting garbage collector in the new ART runtime.

These are both mentioned in this discussion of supporting ART, under "Addressing GC issues": https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html